# Flutter GoRouter StatefulShellRoute push from other StatefulShellRoute (root and not) or boilerplate

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-go-router

I am making a complete Flutter clone of Instagram and trying to implement the navigation exactly like in Instagram. For this task I chose GoRouter and are facing some challenging moments, making some complex navigations.

I want to be able to push one StatefulShellBranch on top of another StatefulShellBranch, but there are a lot of nuances to consider... As an example: have /feed, /timeline, /reels and /profile StatefulShellBranches, need to be able to navigate in /feed to user profile, clicking on avatar on post, meaning that I either need to push /profile on top of /feed(that seems to be easy) or create boilerplate and create the same page as /profile with the same purpose but for navigating to profile outside from /profile. I also need to be able to navigate to user profile from root navigator routes, meaning there is no bottom navigation bar, meaning I can not push StatefulShellBranch on top of that page, therefore, I guess I must create the same page as /profile only for that purpose, because I see no way to navigate to StatefulShellBranch from simple root GoRoute. Also, the problem with pushing /profile on top of other branches, is that it actually does not replace bottom sheets and such things, meaning I can be on post comments page, which is a scrollable bottom sheet and navigating to user will push the /profile page behind the bottom sheet, not on top of it, whereas using separete /user_profile root GoRoute for this job will work.

Overall, it seems that just creating another separate GoRoute for this purpose seems ok, however it requires to create separate instances of Bloc state management for both pages, duplicate the same logic and so on... Also, /profile has it's own sub routes, such as /profile/posts, /profile/statistics, /profile/create_post, etc, meaning that I will also need to duplicate them to access from /user_profile in root navigators, also creating multiple instances of Blocs, which are used in every page and many other repetetive stuff...

I desire to achieve the same behaviour as in Instagram: in cases where you can push branches push them on top of each other, meaning I can still access, lets say /reels page, even though I have navigated multiple time in /feed to /profile, but not to routes that are root. In that case bottom nav bar should disappear and I somehow need to check whether to navigate to /profile or /user_profile, or just /profile with root or not.

Maybe some of you have implemented something similar to this and will help me, or guide me what I am doing wrong in my case. Here is the actual code:

routes with boilerplate:

```
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');

GoRouter router(AppBloc appBloc) => GoRouter(
      navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      initialLocation: '/feed',
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/auth',
          builder: (context, state) => const AuthPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/user/profile/:user_id',
          name: 'user_profile',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final userId = state.pathParameters['user_id'];
            final isSponsored = (state.extra as bool?) ?? false;
            final promoBlockAction =
                state.uri.queryParameters['promo_action'] == null
                    ? null
                    : BlockAction.fromJson(
                        jsonDecode(state.uri.queryParameters['promo_action']!)
                            as Map<String, dynamic>,
                      );

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => CreateStoriesBloc(
                  storiesRepository: context.read<StoriesRepository>(),
                  remoteConfig: context.read<FirebaseConfig>(),
                ),
                child: UserProfilePage(
                  userId: userId,
                  isSponsored: isSponsored,
                  promoBlockAction: promoBlockAction,
                ),
              ),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/user/statistics',
          name: 'user_statistics',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => UserProfileBloc(
                  userRepository: context.read<UserRepository>(),
                  postsRepository: context.read<PostsRepository>(),
                )
                  ..add(const UserProfileFetchFollowersRequested())
                  ..add(const UserProfileFetchFollowingsRequested()),
                child: UserProfileStatistics(tabIndex: tabIndex),
              ),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/user/posts',
          name: 'user_posts',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final userId = state.uri.queryParameters['user_id']!;
            final index = (state.uri.queryParameters['index']!).parse.toInt();

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: MultiBlocProvider(
                providers: [
                  BlocProvider(
                    create: (context) => UserProfileBloc(
                      userRepository: context.read<UserRepository>(),
                      postsRepository: context.read<PostsRepository>(),
                      userId: userId,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                child: UserProfilePosts(
                  userId: userId,
                  index: index,
                ),
              ),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/chat/:chat_id',
          name: 'chat',
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final chatId = state.pathParameters['chat_id']!;
            final chat = ChatInbox.fromJson(state.uri.queryParameters['chat']!);

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: ChatPage(chatId: chatId, chat: chat),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/users/search',
          name: 'search_users',
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final returnUser = state.extra as bool?;

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              fullscreenDialog: true,
              child: SearchUsers(returnUser: returnUser ?? false),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.vertical,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/posts/details/:id',
          name: 'post_details',
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final id = state.pathParameters['id'];

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: PostPreviewPage(id: id ?? ''),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.vertical,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/stories/view',
          name: 'view_stories',
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final author = state.extra! as User;
            final stories = fromListJson(state.uri.queryParameters['stories']!);

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: StoriesPage(stories: stories, author: author),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.scaled,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/stories/create',
          name: 'create_stories',
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final onDone = state.extra as dynamic Function(String)?;

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: StoriesEditor(
              ),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.scaled,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
            return HomePage(navigationShell: navigationShell);
          },
          branches: [
            StatefulShellBranch(
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: '/feed',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                    return CustomTransitionPage(
                      key: state.pageKey,
                      child: const FeedPage(),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                        return FadeTransition(
                          opacity: CurveTween(
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                          ).animate(animation),
                          child: child,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            StatefulShellBranch(
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: '/search',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                    return CustomTransitionPage(
                      key: state.pageKey,
                      child: const SearchView(),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                        return FadeTransition(
                          opacity: CurveTween(
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                          ).animate(animation),
                          child: child,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            StatefulShellBranch(
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: '/profile',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) {

                    return CustomTransitionPage(
                      key: state.pageKey,
                      child: UserProfilePage(),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                        return FadeTransition(
                          opacity: CurveTween(
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                          ).animate(animation),
                          child: child,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  routes: [
                    GoRoute(
                      path: 'create_post',
                      name: 'create_post',
                      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                        return CustomTransitionPage(
                          key: state.pageKey,
                          child: const UserProfileCreatePost(),
                          transitionsBuilder:
                              (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                            return SharedAxisTransition(
                              animation: animation,
                              secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                              transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.vertical,
                              child: child,
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

And here is without boilerplate(however not completed, as I have a lot of issues with that):

```
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'root');

GoRouter router(AppBloc appBloc) => GoRouter(
      navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      initialLocation: '/feed',
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/auth',
          builder: (context, state) => const AuthPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/user/statistics',
          name: 'user_statistics',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            String? userId() {
              final uid = state.uri.queryParameters['user_id'];
              if (uid == null) return null;
              if (uid.isEmpty) return null;
              return uid;
            }

            final tabIndex = (state.extra! as String).parse.toInt();

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => UserProfileBloc(
                  userRepository: context.read<UserRepository>(),
                  postsRepository: context.read<PostsRepository>(),
                  userId: userId(),
                )
                  ..add(const UserProfileFetchFollowersRequested())
                  ..add(const UserProfileFetchFollowingsRequested()),
                child: UserProfileStatistics(tabIndex: tabIndex),
              ),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/chat/:chat_id',
          name: 'chat',
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final chatId = state.pathParameters['chat_id']!;
            final chat = ChatInbox.fromJson(state.uri.queryParameters['chat']!);

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: ChatPage(chatId: chatId, chat: chat),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/users/search',
          name: 'search_users',
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final returnUser = state.extra as bool?;

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              fullscreenDialog: true,
              child: SearchUsers(returnUser: returnUser ?? false),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.vertical,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/posts/details/:id',
          name: 'post_details',
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final id = state.pathParameters['id'];

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: PostPreviewPage(id: id ?? ''),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.vertical,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/stories/view',
          name: 'view_stories',
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final author = state.extra! as User;
            final stories = fromListJson(state.uri.queryParameters['stories']!);

            return CustomTransitionPage(
              key: state.pageKey,
              child: StoriesPage(stories: stories, author: author),
              transitionsBuilder:
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                return SharedAxisTransition(
                  animation: animation,
                  secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                  transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.scaled,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
          parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
            return HomePage(navigationShell: navigationShell);
          },
          branches: [
            StatefulShellBranch(
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: '/feed',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                    return CustomTransitionPage(
                      key: state.pageKey,
                      child: const FeedPage(),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                        return FadeTransition(
                          opacity: CurveTween(
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                          ).animate(animation),
                          child: child,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            StatefulShellBranch(
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: '/timeline',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                    return CustomTransitionPage(
                      key: state.pageKey,
                      child: const TimelinePage(),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                        return FadeTransition(
                          opacity: CurveTween(
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                          ).animate(animation),
                          child: child,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  routes: [
                    GoRoute(
                      name: 'search',
                      path: 'search',
                      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                        final withResult = state.extra as bool?;

                        return NoTransitionPage(
                          key: state.pageKey,
                          child: SearchPage(withResult: withResult),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            StatefulShellBranch(
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  path: '/profile',
                  pageBuilder: (context, state) {

                    return CustomTransitionPage(
                      key: state.pageKey,
                      child: UserProfilePage(
                      ),
                      transitionsBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                        return SharedAxisTransition(
                          animation: animation,
                          secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                          transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
                          child: child,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  routes: [
                    GoRoute(
                      path: 'create_post',
                      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                        return CustomTransitionPage(
                          key: state.pageKey,
                          child: const UserProfileCreatePost(),
                          transitionsBuilder:
                              (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                            return SharedAxisTransition(
                              animation: animation,
                              secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                              transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.vertical,
                              child: child,
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    GoRoute(
                      name: 'profile_create_stories',
                      path: 'create_stories',
                      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
                      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                        final onDone = state.extra as dynamic Function(String)?;

                        return CustomTransitionPage(
                          key: state.pageKey,
                          child: StoriesEditor(
                            onDone: onDone,
                            galleryThumbnailQuality: 900,
                          ),
                          transitionsBuilder:
                              (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                            return SharedAxisTransition(
                              animation: animation,
                              secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                              transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.scaled,
                              child: child,
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    GoRoute(
                      path: 'posts',
                      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                        final extra =
                            state.extra as Map<String, dynamic>? ?? {};
                        final userId = extra['user_id'] as String;
                        final index = extra['index'] as int;

                        return CustomTransitionPage(
                          key: state.pageKey,
                          child: UserProfilePosts(
                            userId: userId,
                            index: index,
                          ),
                          transitionsBuilder:
                              (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                            return SharedAxisTransition(
                              animation: animation,
                              secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
                              transitionType:
                                  SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
                              child: child,
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```